# React component collection works in Dev, but fails in Production

Tags: reactjs, angular

The app I am enhancing at work is based in Angular, but I have been requested to add enhancements using React. I have build a ton of components , which I imported into a collection called "Controls" to simplify the imports on each page (I have also done something similar with my page views). This way rather than importing 15-25 controls on each page, you could simply import Controls, then call to the components  like this:

```
<Controls.ToggleSwitch />
```

This dropped the number of imports I had on each page down from 30+ to about 4-5 and eliminated a ton of duplicated code over all the pages. This worked perfectly when I would do a build in the Dev environment, but when we moved over to doing Prod builds, the parent components fails to render. The app builds with no errors, and I bet no console errors in the browser, the parent component just fails to render.

**Here is an example of my Controls Collection:** (very stripped down of course)

```
import Button from './Button';
import Checkbox from './Checkbox';
import ToggleSwitch from './ToggleSwitch';

const Controls = {

  Button,
  Checkbox,
  ToggleSwitch,
};

export default Controls;
```

**Calling to components this way fails:**

```
import Controls from './Controls';

function Table() {

return(
    <div>
      <Controls.Button />
      <Controls.Checkbox />
      <Controls.ToggleSwitch />
    </ div>

   );
}
```

**But calling to components this way works:**

```
import Button from './Button';
import Checkbox from './Checkbox';
import ToggleSwitch from './ToggleSwitch'

function Table() {

return(
    <div>
      <Button />
      <Checkbox />
      <ToggleSwitch />
    </ div>

   );
}
```

First could someone explain to me why this would work perfectly in my Dev environment, but no longer work once we moved over to Production?

Also, is there a way of creating a collection of components similar to the way I did, but it still work in Prod?

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?